# PostgreSQL JSONB - JSON Array vs JSON Object performance

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

The each object (instance) has its own privacy settings per user. These settings are defined via `privacy JSONB field` in object table row. I'm curious which way is better regards to the performance? Or better aproach at all?

Explanation:

- User with ID 2 can read and write to the object
- User with ID 8 can only read the object
- SQL queries: get records the User with ID 2 can read (assume tasks table)

**Case one** - using array (note: the first key is User ID)

```js
privacy: {
  "2": ["read","write"],
  "8": ["read"]
}
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM "tasks" WHERE (privacy -> '2' ? 'read')
```

**Case two** - using object (not sure in terminology, it is more like hash for me)

```js
privacy: {
  "2": {"read":true, "write":true},
  "8": {"read":true, "write":false}
}
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM "tasks" WHERE (privacy -> '2' -> 'read' = true)
```

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Can you show few examples how're you using this data? I think that answer can depends on that.

Comment: I've added SQL queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I see, if you're asking only about select queries, you can create a `gin` index on `privacy` column (see [8.14.4. jsonb Indexing](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/datatype-json.html)), so basically the following queries should be the same in terms of performance:

```
-- create index
CREATE INDEX privacy_idx ON tasks USING gin (privacy);

SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE privacy -> '2' ? 'read'
SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE privacy @> {"read": true}
```

Probably, there is only one difference in terms of size, because internally jsonb array contains only `WJB_ELEM` for each element and jsonb object - `WJB_KEY` + `WJB_VALUE` for each element.